# Error en Redireccionado con React

Tags: reactjs

Hola gente que tal estoy teniendo un problema con el redireccionado de la web, cuando estoy en localhost/categories/4 y toco el boton ingresar del navbar me lleva a localhost/categories/login en lugar de localhost/login

aqui estan las rutas de mi app

```
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <div>
            <Loading />
              {/* <Navbar  handleToggle={this._handleToggle} /> */}

            <Startup />
            <Switch className="route-wrapper">
              <Route exact path="/" component={ tracker(Home) } />
              <Route exact path="/index.html" component={ tracker(Home) } />
              <Route exact path="/categories" component={ tracker(ListCategories) } />
              <Route exact path="/categories/:cat" component={ tracker(ProductsByCategory, {categoryId: this.props.cat}) } />
              <Route exact path="/search/:s" component={ tracker(Search, {search: this.props.s}) } />
              <Route exact path="/products/:id" component={ tracker(ProductDetail, {productId: this.props.id}) } />
              <Route exact path="/login" component={ tracker(Login) } />
              <Route exact path="/dashboard" component={ tracker(Dashboard) } />
              <Route component={ tracker(NoMatch, {noMatch: true}) }/>
            </Switch>
          </div>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </Provider>
    )
  }
```

Comment: No termino de entender de dónde sale y para qué sirve la función `tracker()` con la que estás envolviendo todos tus componentes.

Comment: la verdad yo tampoco se , pero por lo que vi no influye en nada, yo me encontre el proyecto asi , es del 2017 asique todo puede ser posible

Comment: tracker tiene es una funcion que tiene que ver con google analytics